# Select specific portion of string using Regex match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, patindex

Please consider the below table. I am trying to retrieve only the EUR amount within the `Tax` strings. Some records vary more than the other in size, but the float numbers are always there.

```
OrderID    SKU      Price    Tax
****       ****     ****     [<TV<standard#21.0#false#21.36#EUR>VT>]
****       ****     ****     [<TV<standard#21.0#false#7.21#EUR>VT>]
****       ****     ****     [<TV<standard#17.0#false#5.17#EUR>VT>]
```

I wrote a regular expression that matches what I need: `\d+\W\d+` returns me both float values within the string. In Oracle SQL I can simply get the second occurrence with a query like:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '\d+\W\d+',1,2) FROM table
```

Using the above approach I retrieve `21.36`, `7.21` and `5.17` for those three records.

How can I achieve this with SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server has no native Regex support. If you need/want to use Regex in SQL Server you will need to implement CLR functions. A search for somethnig like "SQL Server Regex CLR Functions" will most certainly give you plenty of choices

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously regex would be the likely tool of choice here.  But SQL Server does not have much native regex support.  Here is a pure SQL Server solution making use of `PATINDEX` and `CHARINDEX`.  It is a bit verbose, but gets the job done:

```sql
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(Tax,
              CHARINDEX('#', Tax, PATINDEX('%[0-9]#%', Tax) + 3) + 1,
              CHARINDEX('#', Tax, CHARINDEX('#', Tax, PATINDEX('%[0-9]#%', Tax) + 3) + 1) -
              CHARINDEX('#', Tax, PATINDEX('%[0-9]#%', Tax) + 3) - 1)
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

The approach is using XML for tokenization of the tax column.
It is producing an XML like below for each row:

```
<root>
  <r>[&lt;TV&lt;standard</r>
  <r>21.0</r>
  <r>false</r>
  <r>21.36</r>
  <r>EUR&gt;VT&gt;]</r>
</root>
```

4th r element is a monetary value in question.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Tax VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Tax) VALUES
('[<TV<standard#21.0#false#21.36#EUR>VT>]'),
('[<TV<standard#21.0#false#7.21#EUR>VT>]'),
('[<TV<standard#17.0#false#5.17#EUR>VT>]');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '#';

SELECT t.*
    , c.value('(/root/r[4]/text())[1]', 'DECIMAL(10,2)') AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
        REPLACE(tax, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
        ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------------------------+--------+
| ID |                   Tax                   | result |
+----+-----------------------------------------+--------+
|  1 | [<TV<standard#21.0#false#21.36#EUR>VT>] |  21.36 |
|  2 | [<TV<standard#21.0#false#7.21#EUR>VT>]  |   7.21 |
|  3 | [<TV<standard#17.0#false#5.17#EUR>VT>]  |   5.17 |
+----+-----------------------------------------+--------+
```